# Finding string between custom tags and doing something with it

Tags: php, string, str-replace

On my new project, members are able to use my YouTube API and it will generate a tag like below for them to use it in whatever textarea they want:

```
<ymedia>http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/qQG0XfU-bFs</ymedia>
```

I want my PHP profile page to take the string between `<ymedia></ymedia>` and generate a similar code below using `$ymstring` for the string collected from the ymedia tag:

```
<?php
$u_agent = $_SERVER[''HTTP_USER_AGENT''];
if(preg_match(''/Opera/i'',$u_agent)){
<object width="320" height="240" data="".$ymstring."?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"><param name="movie" value="".$ymstring."?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgColor" value="#ffffff" /><param name="flashvars" value="vu=".$ymstring."?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" /></object>
} else {
<object width="320" height="240"><param name="movie" value="".$ymstring."?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="".$ymstring."?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="320" height="240"></embed></object>
}
?>
```

Basically, I'm trying to find all the ymedia tags in a $string and replace them with my youtube coding above aimed at either Opera or the rest of other browsers.

Comment: What are you having problems with/what is the question?

Comment: I'm trying to find all the ymedia tags and replace them with my youtube coding above aimed at either Opera or the rest of other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

`preg_match("/<ymedia>(.*?)<\/ymedia>/", $Input, $Matches);`

Then, your result would be in `$Matches[1]` which you could pass as `$ymstring`.

Comment: Will this do this for every ymedia tag found and keep it in it's relative html position?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use preg_replace_callback for simplicity:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('#<ymedia>(http://.*?)</ymedia>#',
         "ymedia_cb", $html);

function ymedia_cb($matches) {
    $url = $matches[1];

    return "<object src=$url>";
}
```

Obviously you would use your if/else construct to return the appropriate and complete object tag.